# How can I save Html content, including input, by user?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div with a number of `textarea` tags. Something like below:

```html
<div id="myDiv">
   TextArea 1: <textarea id="t1">ABC</textarea><br/><br/>
   TextArea 2: <textarea id="t2">DEF</textarea><br/><br/>
   TextArea 3: <textarea id="t3">XYZ</textarea>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the a 'Save' button, I would like to save the content of this div in `localStorage` (including all html markup like tables, etc.) and retrieve it later when the user loads it.

For saving, I use:

```
localStorage.setItem('key1234', $('#myDiv').html());  // Save content of div
```

And to load:

```
$('#myDiv').html(localStorage.getItem('key1234'));  // Load content of div
```

This works very well. But the problem happens when the content of the `textarea` is changed by the user. Even after changing the content to something else, only the original value of the `textarea` tags get saved. I would like to save the full div along with the content of the `textarea` tags at the time of saving.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: problem is he value is not an attribute, it is a property.

Comment: You're saving `myDiv`'s innerhtml. Use `textarea1.value`, etc.

Comment: I need to save the entire content of myDiv (which is loaded dynamically)

Comment: You could concatenate everything as a string together? So <div id="myDiv">Textarea 1: ...</div>

Comment: @HereticMonkey, yes, I think it might work. Let me give it a shot.